# Reset a variable's value from inside of a foreach loop

Tags: php, variables, foreach

I'm working on someone elses code and it looks like there's some issues with the MySQL Insert statement...

> Data truncated for column 'floorSize' at row 1

It seems to do this for quite a few fields, but ideally I want to allow them to be nullable.

So I'm looping through the posted data and looking for an empty string, If it's an empty string, I'd like to reset that variable to NULL. So that the DB can accept a null value instead of a **''** string.

At present, I'm using a foreach loop to see if it the value is empty, Then trying to set that value to NULL. But not having much look

Current code snippet is :

```
function add_user($first_name, $last_name, $gender, $date_of_birth, $address1, $address2, $city, $state, $country, $zip_code, $mobile, $phone, $username, $email, $password, $profile_image, $description, $status, $user_type, $property, $VAN, $agent, $propertyType, $buyerType, $houseName, $street, $postcode, $parish, $zoning, $lat, $lng, $price, $ARV, $tax, $fees, $availableDate, $term, $type, $bedrooms, $bathrooms, $powderrooms, $guestAccom, $furnished, $shortDescription, $floorSize, $plotSize, $pool, $waterfront, $dock, $tennis, $view, $garden, $pets, $fireplace, $laundry, $ac, $patio, $deck, $verandah, $beach, $propertySkipper, $mooring, $gym, $showMap, $display, $videoURL, $garage, $tankSize, $water, $well, $tank, $holiday) {

    global $db;

    $vars = $_POST;

    $count = 0;
    foreach($vars as $k => $v)
    {
        if($v == '')
        {
            $k = NULL;
        }
    }

    //Running Query to add user.
        $query = "INSERT into users VALUES(NULL, '".$first_name."', '".$last_name."', '".$gender."', '".$date_of_birth."', '".$address1."', '".$address2."', '".$city."', '".$state."', '".$country."', '".$zip_code."', '".$mobile."', '".$phone."', '".$username."', '".$email."', '".$password_con."', '".$profile_image."', '".$description."', '".$status."', '', '".date('Y-m-d')."', '".$user_type."', '".$property."', '".$VAN."', '".$agent."', '".$propertyType."', '".$buyerType."', '".$houseName."', '".$street."', '".$postcode."', '".$parish."', '".$zoning."', '".$lat."', '".$lng."', '".$price."', '".$ARV."', '".$tax."', '".$fees."', '".$availableDate."', '".$term."', '".$type."', '".$bedrooms."', '".$bathrooms."', '".$powderrooms."', '".$guestAccom."', '".$furnished."', '".$shortDescription."', '".$floorSize."', '".$plotSize."', '".$pool."', '".$waterfront."', '".$dock."', '".$tennis."', '".$view."', '".$garden."', '".$pets."', '".$fireplace."', '".$laundry."', '".$ac."', '".$patio."', '".$deck."', '".$verandah."', '".$beach."', '".$propertySkipper."', '".$mooring."', '".$gym."', '".$location_id."', '".$showMap."', '".$display."', '".$videoURL."', '".$garage."', '".$tankSize."', '".$water."', '".$well."', '".$tank."', '".$holiday."')";
}
```

So for example $floorSize is set to '' but ideally I want to overwrite to set it to NULL.

My Query is:

```
INSERT into users VALUES(NULL, '', '', '', '2000-01-01', '', '', '', '', 'Bermuda', '', '', '', '', 'amy.peniston@gmail.com', '0cc0d896622bca5f24125fd5e5f2fabb', '', '', 'activate', '', '2019-09-13', 'subscriber', 'PW Property', '', 'sue', '1', '0', '', '', '', 'devonshire', '', '32.309851', '-64.781894', '125000', '100', '1', '2', '', '', 'sale', '3', '3', '1', '0', '0', '', '', '', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '472', '0', '0', '', '0', '', '0', '0', '0', '0')
```

Thanks

Comment: What are all the function parameters for if you're getting the data from `$_POST`?

Comment: Can we see your query?

Comment: Sure, will add the Insert query now

Comment: Please try to insert all your code related to this

Comment: @EdisonBiba all code shown and question updated

Comment: Another issue. Your function receives a lot of arguments which you leave "as is".. Then you're trying to fix the `$_POST` data which you never even use since the query just uses the function arguments directly, without any modification to them.

Comment: @MagnusEriksson is it better to do this before the function is called then?

Comment: @StuBlackett please check my updated answer

Comment: Are you expecting that when `$k = 'first_name'`, that assigning `$k = null;` is the same as `$first_name = null;`? That's not how it works.

Comment: What's the point of setting the variables to null? When you convert `null` to a string, it becomes an empty string, which is the original value that you were replacing.

Comment: @StuBlackett in my updated answer i have given solution even using values from $_POST

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using function params in your insert query. So you shouldn't check values from $_POST.

```
// we can use this function inside of your function to get all paramenters
$params = get_defined_vars();

global $db;

foreach($params as $key => $param){
    if(empty($param)){
        ${$key} = NULL;
    }
    // we need to remove special characters to prevent sql injection
    ${$key} = mysqli_real_escape_string($db, $param);
}

// your query here
```

Anyway this isn't the ideal solution as it may encounter a lot of issues so I would suggest to you to remove all the function parameters since there are a lot and use values directly from `$_POST`.

```
function add_user() {
    global $db;

    $values = $_POST;

    foreach ($values as $key => $value) {
        $values[$key] = mysqli_real_escape_string($db, $value);

        if(empty($value)){
            $values[$key] = 'NULL';
        }
    }


    $first_name = $values['first_name'];
    $last_name = $values['last_name'];
    // .... and all your variables

    // be careful to get the right key from $POST variable when setting these variables

}
```

Comment: He only wants to do this if the value is an empty string.

Comment: Yes and I showed him how to do it. So he just need to add single quotes to the $k variable where he has his condition

Comment: Shouldn't he use a prepared statement to prevent SQL injection?

Comment: Why are you setting `$k`? That's the same mistake he made in his code. You should be setting `$vars[$k]`.

Comment: First issue is that it's in a foreach loop, which, as default, makes both `$k` and `$v` _copies_ of the original values. Changing those won't change the original data. Second issue, why would you set the _key_ as null when its the _value_ that will be inserted?

Comment: I would rather recommend using prepared statements with placeholders instead of manually escaping the data using mysqli_real_escape_string(). And just creating variables dynamically like that is dangerous. If someone would post a param called `db`, it would overwrite the existing `$db`-variable.

Answer (score 2):

`$k` is the key, you need to assign the value. You can do this by making `$v` a reference variable.

```
    foreach($vars as $k => &$v)
    {
        if($v == '')
        {
            $v = null;
        }
    }
```

If you're calling the function like this:

```
add_user($_POST['first_name'], $_POST['last_name'], ...);
```

then you need to put this loop *before* you call the function, not inside the function. And you need to loop over `$_POST`, not another variable that you copy it to (unless you use that variable in the argument list when calling).

Then you need to use a prepared statement. If you just concatenate the variables to the SQL string, `null` will just turn back into an empty string, it won't become a `NULL` value in the database. The prepared statement will also protect against SQL injection.

```
$query = "INSERT into users VALUES(NULL, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, '', ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)";
$stmt = $db->prepare($query);
$date = date('Y-m-d');
$stmt->bind_param("sssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssss", $first_name,$last_name,$gender,$date_of_birth,$address1,$address2,$city,$state,$country,$zip_code,$mobile,$phone,$username,$email,$password_con,$profile_image,$description,$status,$date,$user_type,$property,$VAN,$agent,$propertyType,$buyerType,$houseName,$street,$postcode,$parish,$zoning,$lat,$lng,$price,$ARV,$tax,$fees,$availableDate,$term,$type,$bedrooms,$bathrooms,$powderrooms,$guestAccom,$furnished,$shortDescription,$floorSize,$plotSize,$pool,$waterfront,$dock,$tennis,$view,$garden,$pets,$fireplace,$laundry,$ac,$patio,$deck,$verandah,$beach,$propertySkipper,$mooring,$gym,$location_id,$showMap,$display,$videoURL,$garage,$tankSize,$water,$well,$tank,$holiday);
$stmt->execute();
```

Comment: This will fix the `$vars` values, but it seems like the OP doesn't even use them in for the query (in the code their added to the question)

Comment: I wrote my answer before he showed the query. I assumed he was going to use `$vars` in the query.